# BLAPI > python > Curves Toolkit //blp/irdctk3 interst rate curves sample code

Tags: python, bloomberg

Bloomberg API Core developer guide mentioned the service "Curves Toolkit //blp/irdctk3: The CTK (Curves Toolkit)". In the sample code provided for python, I cannot find any code that uses this.

1. Does anyone have any sample code that uses interest rates curves?
2. In Bloomberg excel formula, we can use formulas like BCurveForward, BCurveStrip to get interest curves and custom interest curves related data. Is there something equivalent in their python API? From their doc, irdctk3 is what i need, but I couldn't find how to use it.

Comment: Also looking to pull interest rate curves from Bloomberg using the CTK. Did you find any solution here? Thanks!

Comment: That is a premium offering only. You can talk to your sales rep.